syntex error with OPA rego file for authentication
I am writing very simple rego file but it is showing syntex error. Can anyone suggest what am I doing wrong?
package example.accesscontrol

# Define the allowed UPNs
allowed_upns = {"xyz@test.com", "abc@test.com" }

# Default deny all access
default allow = false

# Allow access if the UPN is in the list of allowed UPNs
allow {
    input.user.upn in allowed_upns
}

Input
{
      "upn": "xyz@test.com"
}

Error:
1 error occurred: policy.rego:11: rego_parse_error: unexpected identifier token: expected \n or ; or }
        input.user.upn in allowed_upns
                       ^

I was expecting the outcome to be allowed.

To fix this without using import rego.v1 you would need to iterate over the set of allowed_upns to check if any of them match with the input upn as follows:
package example.accesscontrol

# Define the allowed UPNs
allowed_upns := {"xyz@test.com", "abc@test.com"}

# Default deny all access
default allow := false

# Allow access if the UPN is in the list of allowed UPNs
allow {
    allowed_upn := allowed_upns[_]
    input.upn == allowed_upn
}


To use the in keyword you would need to use the import rego.v1 statement and update the code as well to the following:
package example.accesscontrol

import rego.v1

# Define the allowed UPNs
allowed_upns := {"xyz@test.com", "abc@test.com"}

# Default deny all access
default allow := false

# Allow access if the UPN is in the list of allowed UPNs
allow if {
    input.upn in allowed_upns
}

